# How to perform a navigation action after getting the response of an api call on hitting a button in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, button, swiftui, view, navigation

In my SwiftUI application, I have a Button whose action performs an API call. On receiving the response of the API call, how can I navigate to another View ?

Application minimum supporting version is iOS 15. So I cannot use NavigationPath and navigationDestination modifier.

Button is inside a form and on tapping the button, I need to call an API and on getting the response, need to go to next screen.

Comment: By flipping a `Bool`, `append` to a `NavigationPath` , triggering a `selection`, many options, impossible to give you a specific solution.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is the way to do..

```
NavigationLink(destination: PreviewOrderView(), isActive: $showPreview) {
                        EmptyView()
                        
                    }.frame(width: 0, height: 0)
                        .opacity(0)
                    Button("PROCEED") {
                        Task{
                            //API call
                        }
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(RoundedGreenButton(enable: true))
```

as per apple documentation , NavigationLink(destination: , isActive:, labe:) is deprecated in iOS 16
Hence we can use NavigationLink(value:label:) inside a NavigationStack